# Art of electronics condensed

Tags: circuit-design, books

Is there a book similar to the Art of Electronics but in a much more condensed form ? The Art of electronics seems more like a reference book with more than 1000 pages.

Or anyone who has created their own summarised version which can be read online covering all the topics in the above book mentioned ?

Comment: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_%28OpenStax%29/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics%2C_Electricity%2C_and_Magnetism_%28OpenStax%29/16%3A_Electromagnetic_Waves/16.03%3A_Plane_Electromagnetic_Waves

Comment: Dan I have some books in my profile ... Modular Electronics Learning project.. The answer below summarizes all universal Electromagnetic mathematical equations defined by James Clerk Maxwell who published his 1st book in 1873. E is the Electric Field (V/m). B is the Magnetic Field (A/m)  But this is Science , you wanted Art which is just the applications of Physics without so much math.... ;) see profile

Comment: Okay thank you I will check it out :)

Comment: I'm a software engineer turned electronics hobbyist (chose power electronics, one of the hardest, and still don't understand it). I purchased the second edition because it was fairly inexpensive, but contained wisdom in one place you can't get elsewhere -- rule of thumb, here's the shortcut, this is what's going on here, here's where there's a special case and the parasitics overwhelm -- and how to get around it. I leave it where I can read it when I can get a few minutes. There is no short way to transfer wisdom, rules of thumb, and shortcuts, because it's mostly detail-oriented. Sorry

Comment: There is a [used hardback copy of The Art of Electronics second edition on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0521370957), at $32 USD as of June 12, 2020.  I have heard that the third edition contains a lot of updated information on newer chips and technologies, but I have found that the second edition is good for some of the discrete design (including some good low power discrete design I've been studying).  Recommended.  It's a shame this question received a -2, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely!  Here’s the condensed version:

[image]

Comment: Is that supposed to be a joke !

Comment: ...unless your question is a joke.

Comment: Not entirely a joke. I had a professor who said that the best way to teach/learn electronics was to start with Maxwell’s equations and derive everything else from them.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were joking. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually has nothing to do with the art of electronic  design, yet relates EM theory when things interfere.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 While it was kind of a snarky answer, I wouldn't say it has nothing to do with electronic design.  You can derive Ohm's law, and they contain Guass's and Faraday's laws from which you can derive a whole lot of the basic principles of electronic design (inductors, capacitors, antennas, transformers, etc etc).  Of course you need to add some quantum mechanics/semiconductor physics but it's about as compact a description of the electromagnetics part of electronics as you can get.

Comment: That may be so, it is still irrelevant to the art of design or even copying practical designs.